# Game too slow on Oreo

Tags: android, game-loop, android-8.0-oreo

I'm new in Android and I'm trying to write a simple game. 
This is the Main Thread game loop (very simple) that I use (I don't know if is this the problem):

```
    @Override
    public void run(){
        [...]

        while(running) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            canvas = null;

            //try locking the canvas for pixel editing
            //update and draw GameObjects
            [...]

            timeMillis = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
            waitTime = targetTime-timeMillis;

            try{
                this.sleep(waitTime);
            }catch(Exception e){}

            totalTime += System.nanoTime()-startTime;
            frameCount++;
            if(frameCount == FPS){
                averageFPS = 1000/((totalTime/frameCount)/1000000);
                frameCount =0;
                totalTime = 0;

                System.out.println(averageFPS);  //Testing
            }
        }
```

Now... The project use Android 4 API and I'm testing this game on OnePlus 5.
When I upgrade my phone to Android 8, the FPS number has dropped dramatically. With Android 6 I can reach 62 FPS, now (with the SAME code) I can not exceed 13 FPS! 
Why? The problem is in my project or in Android? 
Can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing `canvas.scale (...)` in the main method. 
I cannot explain why the FPS have dropped only after the update of Android Oreo.

Comment: I think there seems to be a known issue with Orio.